# Swagger not generating Web API 2.0 document when code deployed on Azure App service

Tags: swagger, azure-web-app-service

1. Swagger, generating documents perfectly on localhost for web api 2.0 application
2. Swagger, does not generating documents on Azure App service having pay as you go subscription

Could you please suggest any related configuration around azure app service for swagger.

[image]

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]
 public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "FFX WebAPI");
                c.OperationFilter<AuthorizationOperationFilter>();
                c.PrettyPrint();
               
            })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
            {
                c.DocumentTitle("FFX WebAPI");
                c.SupportedSubmitMethods(!int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"],out int result) || result != 4 ? new string[] { "Get", "Post" }: new string[] { });
            });
    }
}

    public class AuthorizationOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.parameters == null)
        {
            operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();
        }
        operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
        {
            name = ApplicationConstants.Token,
            @in = "header",
            description = "enter token",
            required = false, 
            type = "string"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try including ApiKey() in EnableSwagger and EnableApiKeySupport() in EnableSwaggerUi

Comment: don't think ApiKey is required - Some APIs use API keys for authorization. An API key is a token that a client provides when making API calls. The key can be sent in the query string. I need swagger document to be generated as same in localhost @Nayan

Comment: for me , auth token is required in header body is required so i have implement, all are working good in localhost

Comment: <package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net47" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#if DEBUG
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
#else
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
#endif
```

In controller file : Need to check whether explore API settings is enable or disable in build debug and release mode.